# How to find an element inside a ng-repeat in protractor?

Tags: testing, selenium-webdriver, protractor

I am trying to test one website http://www.way2automation.com/angularjs-protractor/banking/#/customer
in this their is one drop down list and i tried with locators by.repeater ,by.model ,getText everything but failed to run the test help me to get out of it.

I am attaching code of my spec and pageObject.

PageObject --

```
var CustomerLoginPage =  function () {

    this.login1 = element(by.buttonText("Login"));
    this.select=element(by.repeater('cust in Customers'));

    this.getCustomer = function () {
        select.getText();
     }

     this.showLogin = function () {
        login1.click();
    };
};
module.exports = CustomerLoginPage;
```

Spec file

```
describe("Customer Login Functionality" , function () {

    browser.sleep(1000);
    it("name details",function () {
        browser.get('http://www.way2automation.com/angularjs-protractor/banking/#');
      //  customer.setName();
        expect(customer.getCustomer()).toEqual('Harry Porter');
         browser.sleep(1000);
    });

    it("show" ,function () {

        customer.showLogin();
        browser.sleep(1000);

    });
});
```

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: login1 and select is not defined

Comment: I got the solution for this .but now i'm getting error locator  element(by.buttonText("Login")); not found.

Comment: In response to element(by.buttonText("Login")) not found, you have commented code for setName().

Comment: Yes @rk30 .The login button is only visible when we select any name from drop down list .

Comment: I got the solution - use element(by.cssContainingText('.btn', 'Login')); for login button  and it will solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Updated Page Objects as -

```
var CustomerLoginPage =  function () {

  this.select=element.all(by.repeater('cust in Customers'));

  this.login1=element(by.cssContainingText('.btn', 'Login'));

  this.getCustomer = function () {
     this.select.getAttribute('value');
  }

  this.showLogin = function () {
      this.login1.click();
  };
};

 module.exports = CustomerLoginPage;
```

and spec file is just like previous one and it's solved my problem.

hope it will help others.